# Dynamically add html tag in textarea

Tags: jquery, laravel

Why is it that my textarea becomes `&lt;b&gt;this is a bold text&lt;/b&gt;` This string is coming from database. It is saved as varchar and I can see it in the database the exact `<b>this is a bold text</b>`.

```
var my_string="{{$string_from_db}}";
$('#my_textarea').val(my_string);
```

I want to make it to dislay the exact text `<b>this is a bold text</b>` in the text area and not the html tags.

Comment: That's not possible using textarea.

Comment: I think its working. https://jsfiddle.net/ntqe83gv/

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Why did it work in your jsfiddle but not in my code.

Comment: At least we now know that this code is working fine, but there is some issue in your system/setup only, which is very difficult for us to find from here.

Comment: You probably encoded the string before (e.g. textarea.value = someOtherDiv.textContent or from the server..)

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes the `<b>this is a bold text</b>` is coming from database. When I alert it, it also becomes `&lt;b&gt;this is a bold text&lt;/b&gt;`

Comment: @turivishal's answer is valid for that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added 2 options you can choose any thing that you want.

**Option 1 - Server Side:** (Laravel)

```php
// Use this
{!! $string_from_db !!}
// instead of
{{$string_from_db}}
```

**Option 2 - Client Side:**

If you don't want to change anything in server side, then you can try this hack, Convert like this using `replace` function,

```js
var my_string = "&ltb&gtthis is a bold text&lt/b&gt";
$('#my_textarea').val(my_string.replace(/&lt/g,'<').replace(/&gt/g,'>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="my_textarea"></textarea>
```

You can use anything from both methods.

Answer (score 3):

Simply instead of using `val` method, use `html` method

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var my_string="&lt;b&gt;this is a bold text&lt;/b&gt;";    
       $('#my_textarea').html(my_string); // <<<< LIKE THIS
    });
</script>
```

JS Bin [**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/mitasukaxi/edit?html,console,output)

> **Notice**: This should be done only for `textarea` and after any necessary validation to prevent any harmful code injection by the
> user.